# More than 2 OR conditions in PHP search

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to PHP and SQL. I'm trying to display search results from my MySQL database via a search box and the SELECT statement I'm using to clarify what results should be displayed will only accept two OR conidtions, and after that won't let me add any more. It just turns gray in Atom and doesn't do anything when I try to search by that condition in the interface. Here is what it looks like in Atom, and the code: [SELECT statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6juL.png)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Clients AS c 
                 INNER JOIN Rentals AS r ON c.Client_ID = r.Client_ID 
                 INNER JOIN Cases AS ca ON r.Client_ID = ca.Case_ID 
                 INNER JOIN Judgments AS j ON ca.Case_ID = j.Case_ID 
                 INNER JOIN Lockouts AS l ON j.Judgment_ID = l.Judgment_ID 
                 WHERE First_name = '$search' OR Last_name = '$search' 
                       OR Phone_number = '$search' OR Email_address = '$search';";
```

I'm wondering how I can add more OR conditions to the SELECT statement, or if there's some other way I should be approaching this. Thank you!

Comment: You can add as many OR as you want. there is no limit for OR. Do you get any error when you run your code? or it's just showing the gray text in Atom?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: This is just a glitch in the syntax highlighting. There's nothing that impacts the actual SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Clients AS c 
                 INNER JOIN Rentals AS r ON c.Client_ID = r.Client_ID 
                 INNER JOIN Cases AS ca ON r.Client_ID = ca.Case_ID 
                 INNER JOIN Judgments AS j ON ca.Case_ID = j.Case_ID 
                 INNER JOIN Lockouts AS l ON j.Judgment_ID = l.Judgment_ID 
                 WHERE c.First_name = '$search' OR c.Last_name = '$search' 
                       OR c.Phone_number = '$search' OR c.Email_address = '$search';";
```

I am assuming that First_name, Last_name etc column is in Clients table that is why i have used c.First_name and so on. As you have aliased Clients table as c.
Note INNER JOIN clause join table if when ON condition meet and get result.
You can use LEFT JOIN clause to get LEFT TABLE (Clients ) event if Join condition not meet.